# Why does the TCP client send the char array correctly but the server can't read it?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, system-calls, serversocket

I have a client which asks the user for a car plate and then (after creating a TCP socket) sends it to the server. I'm quite confident that this step on the client is correct, because what the client shows in the output is exactly what it should be sent, the car plate and 8 byte which is exactly what I want (line 57-66).

The problem with the server, which is a server that can handle both UDP and TCP using `select()`, is that after accepting the TCP connection the `read()` function returns 0, so it means that the server has read nothing basically? (line 221-227), the `errno` inside the `perror()` says `Read: interrupted System call`.

Probably it is a small error, but every time I write this type of code I always face this kind of problem, so I would like to know why it happens.

Here's the client:

```
//librerie da includere
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>

int main(int argc,char ** argv){
    
    int port,sd;
    //host e servaddr
    struct hostent    *host; //host server
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr; //server a cui il client si deve connettere
    
    /* INIZIALIZZAZIONE INDIRIZZO SERVER -------------------------- */
    memset((char *)&servaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    /*
    * NOTA: gethostbyname restituisce gli indirizzi gia' in formato di rete
    */
    host = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (host == NULL) {
        printf("%s not found in /etc/hosts\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    port = atoi(argv[2]);//porta usare ATOI
    
    //SETTARE IL SERVER A CUI ASSOCIARE LA SOCKET
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr *)(host->h_addr))->s_addr;
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(port);
    
    //CREIAMO UNA SOCKET (SD INTERO TRATTATA COME FILE)
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sd < 0) {
            perror("apertura socket");
            exit(1);
    }
    
    /* Operazione di BIND implicita nella connect */
    if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Client: connect ok\n");
    char targa[8];
    char nomeFile[PATH_MAX];
    printf("Dimmi la targa\n");
    int scritto;
    while(fgets(targa,sizeof(targa),stdin)){
        while (getchar()!='\n') ;  // svuoto il buffer da tastiera
        targa[7]='\0';
        printf("invio: %s\n",targa);
        if((scritto=write(sd,targa,strlen(targa)+1))<=0){
            printf("Errore write\n");
            perror("Errore write");
            continue;
        }
        printf("Ho scritto %d\n",scritto);
        int letto; 
        while((letto=read(sd,nomeFile,sizeof(nomeFile)))!=0){

            if(letto==-1){
                perror("Errore read");
                continue;
            }
        
            printf("Ricevuto file %s\n",nomeFile);
            int fd=creat(nomeFile,O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
            if(fd<0){
                perror("Errore creazione file");
                continue;
            }
            char temp;
            int uscito=-1;
            while(read(sd,&temp,1)){
                if(temp!='\0'){
                    write(fd,&temp,1);
                }
                else{
                    close(fd);
                    uscito=0;
                }
            }
            if(uscito==-1)
                close(fd);
        }
        close(sd);
        sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);   
        if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0) {
            perror("connect");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Dimmi la targa\n");
    }
    close(sd);
}
```

Here's the server (the part that I'm struggling with starts at line 221, the UDP part below and the `select()` above should be correct):

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>

#define N 10

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

/********************************************************/
void gestore(int signo)
{
    int stato;
    printf("esecuzione gestore di SIGCHLD\n");
    wait(&stato);
}
/********************************************************/


typedef struct {
    char targa[20];
    char patente[6];
    char tipo[64];
    char img[64];
}Prenotazione;

typedef struct {
    char targa[8];
    char patente[6];
}Richiesta;

typedef struct {
    Prenotazione indice[N];
}Tabella;

int main(int argc,char ** argv){
    int listenfd, connfd, udpfd, nready, maxfdp1;
    fd_set rset;
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;
    int len;
    const int on=1;
    char targa[8];
    char pathImg[13];
    Prenotazione *p=malloc(sizeof( Prenotazione));
    Richiesta * r=malloc(sizeof(Richiesta));
    Tabella tabella;

    char str[20];
    int cont=3;

    strcpy(tabella.indice[0].targa, "AB745LK");
    strcpy(tabella.indice[0].patente, "00001");
    strcpy(tabella.indice[0].tipo, "auto");
    strcpy(str, tabella.indice[0].targa);
    strcat(str, "_img/");
    strcpy(tabella.indice[0].img, str);

    strcpy(tabella.indice[1].targa, "AS734LE");
    strcpy(tabella.indice[1].patente, "00002");
    strcpy(tabella.indice[1].tipo, "camper");
    strcpy(str, tabella.indice[1].targa);
    strcat(str, "_img/");
    strcpy(tabella.indice[1].img, str);

    strcpy(tabella.indice[2].targa, "RT657GH");
    strcpy(tabella.indice[2].patente, "00003");
    strcpy(tabella.indice[2].tipo, "auto");
    strcpy(str, tabella.indice[2].targa);
    strcat(str, "_img/");
    strcpy(tabella.indice[2].img, str);
    /* CONTROLLO ARGOMENTI ---------------------------------- */
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error: %s port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    int nread = 0;
    while (argv[1][nread] != '\0')
    {
        if ((argv[1][nread] < '0') || (argv[1][nread] > '9'))
        {
            printf("Terzo argomento non intero\n");
            exit(2);
        }
        nread++;
    }
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (port < 1024 || port > 65535)
    {
        printf("Porta scorretta...");
        exit(2);
    }
    
    /* INIZIALIZZAZIONE INDIRIZZO SERVER E BIND ---------------------------- */
    memset((char *)&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    printf("Server avviato\n");

    /* CREAZIONE SOCKET TCP ------------------------------------------------ */
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listenfd < 0)
    {
        perror("apertura socket TCP ");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Creata la socket TCP d'ascolto, fd=%d\n", listenfd);

    if (setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on)) < 0)
    {
        perror("set opzioni socket TCP");
        exit(2);
    }
    printf("Set opzioni socket TCP ok\n");

    if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind socket TCP");
        exit(3);
    }
    printf("Bind socket TCP ok\n");

    if (listen(listenfd, 5) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(4);
    }
    printf("Listen ok\n");

    /* CREAZIONE SOCKET UDP ------------------------------------------------ */
    udpfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (udpfd < 0)
    {
        perror("apertura socket UDP");
        exit(5);
    }
    printf("Creata la socket UDP, fd=%d\n", udpfd);

    if (setsockopt(udpfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on)) < 0)
    {
        perror("set opzioni socket UDP");
        exit(6);
    }
    printf("Set opzioni socket UDP ok\n");

    if (bind(udpfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind socket UDP");
        exit(7);
    }
    printf("Bind socket UDP ok\n");
    
    /* AGGANCIO GESTORE PER EVITARE FIGLI ZOMBIE -------------------------------- */
    signal(SIGCHLD, gestore);

    /* PULIZIA E SETTAGGIO MASCHERA DEI FILE DESCRIPTOR ------------------------- */
    FD_ZERO(&rset);
    maxfdp1 = max(listenfd, udpfd) + 1;

    /* CICLO DI RICEZIONE EVENTI DALLA SELECT ----------------------------------- */
    for (;;)
    {
        FD_SET(listenfd, &rset);
        FD_SET(udpfd, &rset);

        if ((nready = select(maxfdp1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            else
            {
                perror("select");
                exit(8);
            }
        }

    /* GESTIONE RICHIESTE TCP ------------------------------------- */
        if (FD_ISSET(listenfd, &rset))
        {
            len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
            if ((connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &len)) < 0)
            {
                if (errno == EINTR)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    perror("accept");
                    exit(9);
                }
            }

            if (fork() == 0)
            { /* processo figlio che serve la richiesta di operazione */
                close(listenfd);
                char pwd[PATH_MAX];
                if(getcwd(pwd,sizeof(pwd))==0){
                    printf("Errore getcwd\n");                             //restituisce pwd
                    perror("Error getcwd");
                    exit(0);
                }
                printf("pwd :%s\n",pwd);
                printf("Dentro il figlio, pid=%i\n", getpid());
                int letto;
                if (letto = read(connfd, targa, sizeof(targa)) <= 0) {
                    printf("Errore read, letti %d byte\n", letto);
                    perror("Read");
                    exit(1);
                }
                targa[letto] = '\0';
                printf("Targa: %s \n",targa);
                strcpy(pathImg,targa);
                strcat(pathImg,"_img/");
                char Path[PATH_MAX];
                sprintf(Path,"%s/%s",pwd,pathImg);
                printf("Percorso directory %s\n",Path);

                DIR *imgDir = opendir(Path);//apro directory
                struct dirent *dp; //struttura su cui passare i vari file della directory
                if (imgDir == NULL)
                {
                    perror("Errore apertura file");
                    continue;
                }
                while((dp = readdir(imgDir)) != NULL){
                    struct stat * statFile;
                    char filePath[PATH_MAX];
                    sprintf(filePath,"%s/%s",Path,dp->d_name);
                    if(stat(filePath,statFile)<0){
                        perror("Error stat file");
                        closedir(imgDir);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    if(S_ISREG(statFile->st_mode)){
                        if(write(connfd,dp->d_name,sizeof(dp->d_name)<=0)){
                            perror("Errore write");
                            break;
                        }
                        int fd=open(filePath,O_RDONLY);
                        if(fd<0){
                            perror("Errore File");
                            break;
                        }
                        char temp;
                        while(read(fd,&temp,1)>0){
                            if(write(connfd,&temp,1)<=0){
                                perror("Errore write file");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        temp='\0';
                        if(write(connfd,&temp,1)<=0){
                            perror("Error write socket");
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                closedir(imgDir);
                printf("Figlio %i: termino\n", getpid());
                shutdown(connfd, 0);
                shutdown(connfd, 1);
                close(connfd);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            } // figlio-fork
            /* padre chiude la socket dell'operazione */
            shutdown(connfd,0);
            shutdown(connfd,1);
            close(connfd);
        } /* fine gestione TCP */     
    
    /* GESTIONE UDP ------------------------------------------ */
        if (FD_ISSET(udpfd, &rset))
        {

            len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

            if(recvfrom(udpfd,r,sizeof(Richiesta),0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &len)<0){
                perror("recvfrom");
                continue;
            }
            printf("Ricevuta richiesta UDP\n");
            printf("Targa:%s \t Patente:%s\n",r->targa,r->patente);
            short esito=-1;
            for(int i=0;i<cont;i++){
                if(strcmp(tabella.indice[i].targa,r->targa)==0){
                    strcpy(tabella.indice[i].patente,r->patente);
                    esito=0;
                    printf("Prenotazione modificata\n:");
                    printf("Targa:%s \t Patente:%s\n",tabella.indice[i].targa,tabella.indice[i].patente);
                }
            }
            short shortrete = htons(esito);
            if (sendto(udpfd, &esito, sizeof(esito), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, len) < 0) {
                perror("Sendto error");
                continue;
            }

            close(udpfd);

        //operazioni server.....
        } /* fine gestione richieste di conteggio */

    } /* ciclo for della select */
    /* NEVER ARRIVES HERE */

}
```

Comment: If `read()` doesn’t return -1 the value of `errno` is meaningless. If it returned zero the peer has disconnected, and this is not an error.

Comment: Why is the client closing and reconnecting its socket after every `write()`? Don't do that, leave the connection open and just reuse it.  You are delimiting your messages with `'\0'`, that is sufficient. When the server detects a TCP client is readable, it can read from that client until that `'\0'` is encountered.

Comment: @user207421 peer has disconnected because the server enters into the if condition after the read and the child process is terminated, my question is about the read above that returns 0

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm doing that because every time the while block starts a different child handle that, I see every while block as a different connection

Comment: @ric you are re-connecting to the same server on each loop iteration. It looks like you are connecting to the server, asking it for a file, receiving that file, and then disconnecting and reconnecting. That is a waste of TCP resources. You can request and transfer multiple files over a single TCP connection. There is no need to disconnect after each file. Just don't use socket EOF to signal file EOF. Send the file size before sending the file data, that way the client knows when to stop reading and move on to the next file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're right about that, but the server after receving the car plat (which doesn't happen and that's what I don't get) opens a directory ans send all the file inside the directory , so the client has a different connection for every car plate that send

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the advise of the file size, is defintely more reasonable

Answer (score 1):

In your server, on line 221, you are missing some required parenthesis.

On this line:

```c
if (letto = read(connfd, targa, sizeof(targa)) <= 0) {
```

You are setting `letto` to the wrong value, as the `<=` operator has higher precedence than the `=` operator. The compiler will evaluate `read(...) <= 0` before it evaluates `letto = ...`, so you end up setting the value of `letto` to the result of `<=` rather than the result of `read()`.

That line needs to be like this instead:

```c
if ((letto = read(connfd, targa, sizeof(targa))) <= 0) {
    ^                                          ^
```

Compare this to your client code, where lines 60 and 67 have similar statements that are using the extra parenthesis correctly:

```c
if((scritto=write(sd,targa,strlen(targa)+1))<=0){
   ^                                       ^
...
while((letto=read(sd,nomeFile,sizeof(nomeFile)))!=0){
      ^                                        ^
```

This is why I always advise people NOT to assign a variable and compare its value in the same statement! You should separate them to avoid this problem, eg:

```c
letto = read(connfd, targa, sizeof(targa));
if (letto <= 0) {
```

Comment: Correct, but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem because the value of letto is always 0

Comment: In the original code, yes, because `<=0` would return `false` when `read()` returns `>0` on *success*, and `false` converts to `0` when assigned to an `int`.  In the fixed code, `letto` would be whatever value `read()` actually returns, and would be `0` ONLY when the client disconnects (which you are actually doing).

Comment: the client disconnects after that, before doing that it does other stuff, do you think is already disconnected, or maybe the client disconnects because the server disconnects first with the SIGCHILD and so the client in the following read() reads EOF?

Comment: in fact that's what the server output is:  `code`                                                    
    Errore read, letti 0 byte
    Read: Interrupted system call
    esecuzione gestore di SIGCHLD '

Comment: @ric as you were already told earlier, `errno` has no meaning when `read()` returns exactly `0` on a disconnect, it is only meaningful when `read()` returns `<0` on failure, so DON'T use `perror()` on a disconnect.

Comment: again... thanks for your advice, you're right but my questions is why letto is 0 and targa doesn't contain what the client send, you guys are saying to me all kind of problems to resolve except for what I'm asking

Comment: @ric You were already told *multiple times* that `read()` on a socket returns `0` ONLY when the peer disconnects. So, that is what you need to debug for yourself. Your client is disconncting before the server receives everything it is expecting. That is where you need to focus your efforts on troubleshooting.